# How to get CSS Variables working in Dart

Tags: css, dart, polymer

I've looked for this on the internet, but cannot find a working example. Can someone direct me to get CSS variables working in Dart.
source:
http://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables/
Someone mentioned csslib, but I don't see a solution per:
https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/16710
https://github.com/dart-lang/csslib/issues/9

I'm trying to get this working inside of polymer component:

```
:host {
    --text-color: #4f1f91;
}
.someLabel {
  color: var(--text-color);
}
```

I understand I could use dart/polymer variables and do something like this:

```
.someLabel {
  color: {{ polymerVar }};
}
```

But, why are CSS variables not working on 08/2015??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox is currently the only browser with native support for CSS variables http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables
Polymer 1.0 provides a polyfill for the other browsers. Polymer.dart 0.17 (the Dart port of Polymer.js 1.0)  is currently alpha state but it can be already experimented with (see the last [dart-polymer](/questions/tagged/dart-polymer) questions). 
I don't know if the polyfills can be used without Polymer.